# What are the differences between Jacobs Krönung and Jacobs Cronat Gold?

Tags: flavor

Jacobs got two major brands:

[image]         vs.         [image]

As far as I can tell, they are both instant freeze dry coffee going [through the same process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeze-drying#Coffee).

However, Cronat Gold is  (at least in my country) 30%-50% cheaper than  Krönung. The taste is also very similar, the Cronat Gold maybe bit more delicate or having less caffeine.

What are the differences between the two, and why such a gap in the price?

Comment: I just tried Cronat Gold in a hotel in northern Germany. It did not taste anything like the coffee I drink in the US. It tasted more like tea with lemon. I typically drink fresh ground coffee, black, no sugar, not instant. However, even with instant, I prefer a darker richer flavor. I will see if the hotel carries the Kronung, it sounds darker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jacobs Cronat Gold is smoother and more mild than Jacobs Krönung Instant coffee.
Krönung is blended with coffee of various regions across the world, Cronat Gold is not. It's the closest to home-brewed coffee (i.e coffee from the European Highlands). 
No idea about the cost difference though.

Sourced from http://www.enjoybettercoffee.com/

Comment: Coffee from “the European Highlands”? Now that has me wondering where Coffee might grow in Europe . Could you elaborate, please?